# if condition in where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I write a query that if one column value is not null then compare the value with the querystring, else do not compare the column value.

for example, I have a tbl1 with programs1 and programs2 two columns, the value in these two columns can be null or with value. I want to have the if statement that say

```
if programs1 is not null, programs1=@programs  and 
if programs2 is not null, programs2=@programs
```

my query is like this:

```
select * from tbl1 where
(programs1 is not null and programs1=@programs)
and 
(program2 is not null and programs2=@programs)
```

but it didn't work the way I want. How do I write a correct query for this case? TIA.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with `asp.net`? Looks like a SQL question. Please retag properly.

Comment: Please give some detail about 'it didn't work the way I want'.

Answer (score 7):

I *believe* you're looking for [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx).

```
WHERE COALESCE(programs1, programs2) = @Programs
```

However, if you'd like to compare only if it has a value:

```
-- If the column is null, ignore it. If it has a value, then
-- check that value.
WHERE (programs1 IS NULL OR programs1 = @Programs)
  AND (programs2 IS NULL OR programs2 = @Programs)
```

<sub>Also, I assume you mean [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) since you reference [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)</sub>

Comment: Downvoter--feedback please? This have to do with them using "and"? (The original question implied to use the first column by preference, with fallback to the second which is why I offered `COALESCE`). (Just FYI)

Comment: Yes that was the reason.  After re-reading his question 15 times I still can't figure out exactly what he's asking for and your reasoning make sense, so I reversed.

Comment: You are right. it is sql-server. I tried your where condition, the comparion results didn't work. It still displays everything.

Comment: @user: Try my updated answer (second half) and see if that improves the situation.

Comment: I tried this one: WHERE COALESCE(programs1, programs2) = @Programs

Comment: and WHERE (programs1 IS NULL OR programs1 = @Programs)   AND (programs2 IS NULL OR programs2 = @Programs) Both are not working.

Comment: @user: Then I'm not 100% positive I understand the issue. Can you maybe edit question with a few example rows of data, and the results you'd like to see returned? Then I can do my best to create a query that works for you.

Comment: It looks like the where statement does not work no matter what I changed. It returns all results. The programs1 and programs2 is nvarchar(255). I don't know what it is wrong. My sql statement is: "select * from tbl1 where programs1=@programs or programs1 is null" @programs is a querystring("programs") passed from the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from   tbl1
where  (programs1=@programs or programs1 is null)
  and  (programs2=@programs or programs2 is null)
```

Comment: Please make sure to indent all code 4 spaces or select your code and hit ctrl+k / press code button (this formats the code block legibly).

Comment: not working. Let me explain it again. I have the first page with a drpdown box that user can select one program from it. the selectedvalue is passed to the next page, my table programs1 and programs2 values are either null or have value. if the programs1 colum value is not null, then compare the value with the querystring; if the programs2 value is not null then compare the value with querystring.

Answer (score 0):

```
ISNULL(programs1,programs2) = @Programs
```

or

```
(programs1 is not null and @Programs = programs1) or (programs2 is not null and @Programs = programs2)
```

Comment: something like below, but for some reason, it still doesn't work:(programs2 is null and (programs1=@programs or programs1 is null)  or (programs2 is not null and (programs1=@programs or programs1 is null ) or programs2=@programs  ))

Comment: What do you want to happen in order? if p1 is null then compare p2? if p2 is null then false or if p2 is null compare p1?


or